# confusion with regard to constructive axiom

Tags: formal-methods, software-verification

[image][image]we say that a constructive axiom is an equality axiom $u = s$ :

- whose left member $u$ is a pattern,
- whose right member $s$ is any term whose variables are all appearing in $u$.

and yet we say of $suc(i + j) = i + suc(j) $ is not constructive, Ok, and
this $dump(push(e, s), t) = dump(e, push(s, t))$ is constructive.

But why the last one is constructive, when $e$ appears inside $dump$ and not outside of it, like $j$ in the former example?

Comment: Ok, so this is using terminology that is different from what I'm used to. Please add a reference to the book, or link to it if it's online, because to explain this, we need to know other definitions: what's a generator? How are the integer and queue abstract data types defined?

Comment: I only have lecture notes, a generator is a constructor. I have included it how integer is defined

Comment: Can you help with specifiying the ternary operator `_?_:_` having 0 acting as false, and suc(0) as true?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: The fact that `Nat` is a free data type means the constructors are given in the specification. In order to answer your question you need to supply a specification in which the equation `(ℎ(,),)=(,ℎ(,))` occurs.